# Unexpected token and missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm having an issue with the phonegap ported versions of my app on several devices. On some devices the error (alert) is: "missing ) after argument list", while on other devices "Unexpected token =>".

```
{   <div class="container home-menu">
    <div class="row content-1">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <!-- Menu -->
            <img style="height:90px;" src="res/images/splash_logo.png"/><br>
(unless: (saved-games:) contains $_autosave_slot and (datavalues: (saved-
games:)) contains $_autosave_filename)[(goto: $_start_passage)]
}''<span class="home-button">[[New->$_start_passage]]</span><br>
<span class="home-button">(link: "Continue")[(load-game: $_autosave_slot)]
</span>''<br><a href="#" onClick="closeMeNow();" class="home-
button">Exit</a>
            <!-- Credits -->
<div class="bottom-links"><a href="contact.html"><span style="color: 
white;">some text</span></a><br>
            <a href="credits.html"><span style="color: white;">some text</span></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
<script> function closeMeNow() { navigator.app.exitApp();} </script>
```

Comment: I would recommend looking for the error in the HTML and code as it is seen in the browser. Most pc browsers will show this when pressing the F12 key.  The error is probably there on all browsers, but only some will show the error to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by addding my other JS code to the generated .html file or as an external source, rather than directly into engine I worked with.